# Docker + MongoDB: How to view database with RoboMongo?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I access the mongo database that created by Docker using RoboMongo or something similar?

Before using Doncker, I have already install mongodb into my Linux machine. So I can't use the port "27017:27017" in the docker-compse.yml. I use "27018:27018":

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - /data/mongodb/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
```

I can use RoboMongo to view all the databases that I created in my pre-docker mongo. But how can I access the Docker's?

This is my DockerFile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /opt/app/

WORKDIR /opt/app
ADD . /opt/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**EDIT:**

When I run the docker on my terminal:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting dummyapp_mongo_1
Recreating dummyapp_web_1
Attaching to dummyapp_mongo_1, dummyapp_web_1
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=571498710dc0
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.1
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.083+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.104+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.104+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.104+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.104+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:35.104+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1454M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.385+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.389+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mongo_1  | 2017-01-03T10:20:36.390+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
web_1    | 
web_1    | > dummy-app@0.0.0 start /opt/app
web_1    | > node ./bin/www
```

**EDIT 2:**

A new error below after changing the port to  "27018:27017" when I am on GET http://localhost:3000/data/from/db or POST http://localhost:3000/data/into/db :

```
failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect

MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/opt/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:325:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/opt/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:173:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have your mongodb listening on port 27018 in the container?  Based solely on the information in your post, I'm guessing mongodb is listening on its default port, 27017, within the container, and you're mapping host 27018 to container 27018 which mongo isn't listening on.  That `ports` item should look like this: `27018:27017` so that the unused port on the host, 27018, is mapped to the correct port on the container, 27017.

This exposure is irrelevant to the npm container because it uses a different mechanism to expose the ports, with a link between the containers.  You'd find that if you put your other mongodb clients in containers, a link would also work for them.  But to interact from the host, you'll need to expose the correct port in the container to an available port on the host.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ports

Comment: I thnk you are right - see my edit above. I don't know what those lines trying to say really. But I can see the database created under Docker anyway with RoboMongo. Any ideas?

Comment: can I ask - what are 27018 and 27017 referring to in `27018:27017`?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ports explains that the first number is the port to forward on the host, and the second is the port to forward it to on the container.  They don't have to be different as far as docker is concerned, but in your case the host is already using 27017 so you had to change it.  That link provides more information.

Comment: I have changed it to `27018:27017`. and run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` but everything is still the same as before.

Comment: did you tell your client, robomongo, to connect to 27018 this time?

Comment: Aww it works now when I run robomongo again thanks!. But I don't understand - why 27017 in `27018:27017`? `ports (HOST:CONTAINER)` doesn't explain much.

Comment: host is the system running docker.  container is the system running _in_ docker.  Inside docker, mongo is running on 27017.  So your'e saying, 27018 on the host, should be forwarded to 27017 in the container.  you're doing the same thing with npm, but on port 3000 where npm listens by default, and there's no conflict there so you can use the same port.  If this is a little over your head, you may want to familiarize yourself with the concepts of tcp/ip ports which should make it crystal clear.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I have a new error after changing the port to `27018:27017` - see my edit 2 above. what is going on?

Comment: Are you still getting 'waiting for connections on port 27017' in the output?

Comment: when I was on `27018:27018`, I have added some data into the database called `dummy-app`. It might be causing the problem? And yes, still getting  `waiting for connections on port 27017` in the output.